# connect sql database to excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am using excel as a frontend to generate various reports from sqlserver..
It is working fine..
But for each report I have use Id and Pwd ..
How do I establish connection on opening an excel?
i mean
can I avoid using pwd for each report i deploy using vba?

Comment: It should be possible to create a data connection file, which then can be used within your Excel.

Comment: Use a trusted connection? Then the credentials of the authenticated windows user is used.